# Video can play in UIWebIView using href but not using <video> tag

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm experimenting playing video in a UIWebView. If I have some html like this:

```
 <a href="sample_mpeg4.mp4"><img src="Video_v3.png"></a>
```

then then video will play. But if I use the  tag like this, then it doesn't do anything:

```
 <video src="sample_mpeg4.mp4">The mp4</video>  
or 
 <a href="my ref"><video src="YouTube.3gp"></a>
```

A play button gets displayed suggesting that the video will play (but there is no image from the video behind the play button), but when you click on the play button nothing happens - shouldStartLoadWithRequest: doesn't get invoked like it would for an image for example.

According to this link this should work, but does not. Any idea why not?

http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/html-5-video-and-audio-in-uiwebview-and-webview/

Comment: Try adding a width and height to the video tag?

Comment: No luck with something like <video src="sample_mpeg4.mp4" controls width="120" height="80"></video>

Comment: it would be controls="controls"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that allowsInlineMediaPlayback is set to YES. This is set to NO by default.

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```